# Lenovo G500 Re-booting failed

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have a Lenovo G500.  Yesterday it asked me to reboot the system.  I did.  Now it wont come back on.  I have tried everything I read online like taking out the battery and holding the power button in for 20 seconds, then switching on the pc with only the ac adapter plugged in.  I still only see the backlight of the pc, nothing else.  I also tried to hold in the Fn key and tried all other F keys (F2, F12, etc.) I also pressed that little button next to the power button, but nothing is responding.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a hardware failure try to do the following.

1.remove the cmos battery and re install.

2.remove your Ram and clean it using eraser and install it again.

and let me know if you are hearing any beep sounds.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but can I just ask you, why now all of a sudden could it be a hardware failure?  I didn't have any problems before it asked me to reboot.  If this is the case, I will have to take my laptop in to a repair store because I don't even know what cmos battery is or how to clean the ram.  Haha.  I'm useless with computers.

Comment: Okay but you'r only telling that you just rebooted it and now it is not coming, how can it be. either os failure but if os fails you will see some text error, Can you able to go in bios. if yes let me know.

Comment: and screen is directly connected to your ram so it may be ram problem.

Comment: I am not able to go in bios.  Also I don't hear any beeps when I switch on the laptop.

Comment: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/9066-display-problem-laptop

Comment: see the link it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple way Bring it to the Lenovo support center.
If it has warranty it is free of cost.They will fix it in three or four days.
Good luck>